# How to fetch an object with the highest index in a list of buttons?

Tags: vb.net, list, event-handling

I have created a click event for 4 Buttons, where if a button is clicked it is added to a list called `buttonslist`. Now all I need to do is to check if the button with the highest value out of 4 backcolor is red or blue. (program - visual basic 2010)
What do you guys suggest me ?

This is what i have tried :

```
Dim buttonList As New List(Of Button)

Private Sub buttons_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles b1.Click, b4.Click, b5.Click, b8.Click
    Dim selectedBtn As Button = sender
    buttonList.Add(selectedBtn)
End Sub

Public Sub checkitems()
    For Each b As Button In buttonList
        If b.BackColor.Equals(buttonList(3).BackColor) AndAlso buttonList(3).BackColor = Color.Red Then
            Label5.Text += 1
        Else
            Label6.Text += 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: First, you should set [`Option Strict On`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for [this project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#to-set-option-strict-in-the-ide) and make it the [default for new projects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement#to-set-the-option-strict-default-setting-for-new-projects). Correct the problems it shows you. Then, instead of `.Equals`, try using `=`.

Comment: Still not working, all i need to do now is to check if the last button added to the list is color red or blue. I dont know if it needs a function or just a sub for this?

Comment: You don't need a loop to get the last item of a list: you could do `If buttonList.Last().BackColor = Color.Red Then`...